# Application pool account permission to run RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

Recently my web server (windows server 2012 R2) got several Windows updates. Since then I am not able to run a code involving RestSharp. It fails whenever I try to initialize "new RestRequest()". Windows event log registers this error: "User does not have permission to run the resource"

I have development environment with Windows 7 where I don't see these updates. My code runs fine.

I have looked into the update history on the server and looks like the following updates may be creating these problems.

KB3074548
KB3074228
KB3074545

I have looked into documentation of RestSharp to find out whether any specific permission needed on the application pool running RestSharp code. I could not find out anything.

I am wondering whether anyone else having this problem and/or may have any knowledge about permissions required to run RestSharp request.

Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is now working. It was just a deployment issue.